# JWT Bearer Token not authorizing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a question regarding about my JWT token been authorizing. I have created a JWT token and I'm trying to authorize it for a controller to test but it keeps mentioning that the 'user' is unauthorized to access the controller. I know that it has to do with the issuer since it has a different port number, however, I gave it the correct port number and it stills gives me a 401 Unauthorized code. I have no idea what else to do. I'm using .NET 6, VS Code, and the port number that is being heard is https://localhost:7139. What else am I missing here?

#### AuthController.cs

This generates the jwt token when someone logs in or registers

```
private async Task<AuthResultVM> GenerateJWTToken(User user)
        {
            var authClaims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var authSignInKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSignInKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            var response = new AuthResultVM()
            {
                Token = jwtToken,
                ExpiresAt = token.ValidTo
            };

            return response;
        }
```

#### AccountController

I added the Authorize attribute to validate the token but it keeps mentioning 401 Unauthorized

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public AccountController(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("This is the AccountContoller");
        }
    }
```

#### appsettings.js

```
"JWT": {
    "Secret": "this-is-just-a-strong-key",
    "Audience": "user",
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:44347"
    // This is where I change the Issuer to localhost:7139 but still get 401 error code
  }
```

#### Program.cs

```
// Other Code
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.configuration["JWT:Secret"])),

        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],

        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
    };
});

//Other code
```

Comment: You may need :  [AllowAnonymous]    [Route("login")]    [HttpPost]  See : https://www.codemag.com/Article/2105051/Implementing-JWT-Authentication-in-ASP.NET-Core-5

Comment: The `[AllowAnonymous]` will defeat the purpose of this controller. Only logged in users can access their accounts. @jdweng

Comment: Still try to isolate issue.  Route("login") may help.  If AllowAnonymous works than you know it is a login issue and not something else.

Comment: Ok so I removed the `[Authorize]` and added `[AllowAnonymous]`. It works fine with the `[AllowAnonymous]` it is the JWT token and it has to do with the different ports. I know that for sure but even if the issuer is the same as the localhost it still gives me an error. Basically I'm asking if I'm giving the exact port, why is it giving me a 401 error? What am I not understanding here? @jdweng

Comment: Not sure.  I think the token is correct and the login account is the issue.

Comment: Yeah I found the issue to my problem in my program.cs file I had the `app.UseAuthorization();` code was before `app.UseAuthentication();`. After correcting this to authenticate first and then authorize it was working fine. It was the order of the middleware that was throwing me off @jdweng